# PHP - Set a Variable within while loop

Tags: php

I'm currently trying to set a variable within a while loop equal to different values of an array. I have my select statement setup so that it pulls the information successfully and can be displayed by echoing the relevant classes. However, if I try to set the rows equal to a variable on the second pass it doesn't run and completes the while loop.

```
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$hostname = "xxx";
$database = "xx";
$dbhandle = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database) or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

$date = "1996-03-12 12:03:00";

$selectcmd = "SELECT starttime, endtime, partner, worklist, serviceloss, servicereference, siteaddress, ticketref FROM work WHERE starttime='$date'";

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection  Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$result = $conn->query($selectcmd);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
        $body = $row["starttime"].$row["endtime"];
        require "mail.php";
    }
} else {
    echo "No Mail To Send";
}

$conn->close();
```

mail.php is the PHPMailer function and sends emails fine.

I know the issue is that I'm trying to set a variable within the while loop. However, I'm not sure how to overcome this. I've attempted to unset the body at the end of the while loop.

mail.php for those who asked:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
try {                                
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'localhost';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;                              
    $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           
    $mail->Port = 25;

    $mail->setFrom('test@test.com', 'test');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net');                    

    $date = "today";
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = 'Important Notification';
    $mail->Body    = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    die();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die();
}
```

Comment: Why are you requiring the mail.php in the while loop? Heck, why are you requiring it at all? You can call the mail() function directly.

Comment: Are you sure that you actually have multiple rows where starttime = "1996-03-12 12:03:00"

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata I'm using the mail.php as it declares other variables which are constant throughout. The only variable that changes is the $body.

Comment: @PatrickQ There are indeed. I took out of the code above "echo $result->num_rows;" which returns 2. I've direct access to the database which currently only has two entries.

Comment: while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) ???  ==   <=   >=

Comment: @metalbox What?

Comment: Show `mail.php` maybe there is a header redirect or `die()` or something.

Comment: I do not know, I'm crazy, but I think he should check the while, or not?

Comment: @metalbox the while loop runs until `$result->fetch_assoc()` returns false, meaning there are no more rows to fetch.

Comment: @AbraCadaver good call. It `die`d.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I've added the mail.php where there is indeed a die() function. However, if I thought this was what would be expected as the script would be completed on the first instance. Then when it's called on the second pass it would run the entire script again and then die.

Comment: @AlexanderWay `die` doesn't affect only the script that contains it. It ends execution of the script that includes or requires that script as well.

Comment: @Don'tPanic ah! That's useful information, thank you. However, if I remove the die() function then it complains that I Cannot redeclare a class within the phpmailer.php script. Do I need to change it to require_once?

Comment: @AlexanderWay `require` does not execute the provided file as a new thread. It simply includes the code within that file into the currently-running code (just like `include` does, but produces a fatal error if it can't include the file).  Plus, there's really no need for you to be including all of that each time through the loop anyway. Set it all before the loop, then just update `$mail->Body` each time through and then call `$mail->send();`

Comment: @PatrickQ Patrick, Thank you. That sounds logical. I'll try now and update shortly on the results :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was as @PatrickQ advised.
The die() function was causing the script to stop running altogether. I removed this from mail.php and then moved the require 'mail.php' to outside the while loop. I then added the $mail->send(); function to the while loop.

Everything is as I wish :)